# Want to generate ER diagram with weak associations. where to define attributes file

Tags: schemacrawler

I am running SchemaCrawler through docker container.
I have tables in database ORACLE in which all tables does not have explicit foreign key referential constraints. I want to generate ER diagram with weak associations.
But don't know where to define weak attributes in an attributes file and load them. Can you please guide me.

Comment: How to update weak-associations.yaml file in docker container and generate ER diagram. I have checked https://www.schemacrawler.com/attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at your previous question, [Cannot write output file in schemacrawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67668259/cannot-write-output-file-in-schemacrawler). At this point, you will have mounted the "./share" directory to "C:\Program Files\SchemaCrawler\share". You can create the attributes file in that directory. Let us say the file is called "attributes.yaml". You can then refer to it using `--attributes-file ./share/attributes.yaml` when you run the Docker container.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have created attributes.yaml file and passed into the command also. ER diagram is created but its not showing weak relation between tables. As In my database ,primary key is not defined on any tables. Is it necessary to define primary key on tables? In attributes file I have mentioned referenced-table and referencing table.

Comment: If this is a back and forth question and answer session, please use https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/discussions